Fit/Adjust google ad in mobiles
Im using Google Ads in my site inside a card > inside a container.
The problem is the red circles in the picture. How can i fix this issue? I need to fit/adjust the size of the ad to the card or container.
This problem only happens in mobiles. Thanks so much.


The places you specify go beyond the container.
Probably, the color of the buttons depends on the settings of the advertising campaign or the color of the banner in it.
I doubt you will be able to change the settings how you want.
https://prnt.sc/qWf6Km5lEzaX

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
